# Node js Module to convert PDF document to Word document

Tags: node.js, pdf

I am working on one Node project where I need to convert PDF document into Word document but I am not sure if there is any module available for this.

It's true that PDF can contain such styling which is hard to edit it in Word document so is there any alternative which I can use.

I tried converting PDF -> HTML -> Word but then the formatting in Word is looking really bad and it doesn't seems to be working as expected.

Comment: as far as I know, there are few libraries to convert PDF => JSON format. With JSON, you can use it to render HTML correctly. It cost time but it's worthy to do ( you'll learn a lot ;) )